# Is video editing permissible in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram

One of the my friend is a wedding photographer.  I am interested in working on video editing, which I told him. He agreed to teach me video editing.
Now I have a doubt:  Is video editing permissible in Islam? I searched in google but I couldn't get clear answer. Is it permissible to edit the wedding videos?

Comment: Does editing imply you will look at non-mehram & add music to the video? If yes, I hope you already know what to expect as an answer from an Islamic perpective.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's permissible if you're doing it for work purpose but looking at girls in video for your sexual pleasure is not permissible.

Comment: is there any fatwa regarding this..?